# Como verificar se um LocalDate é um fim de semana?

Tags: java, data, java-8

Eu tenho a seguinte data do tipo `LocalDate`

```
2017-12-21
```

Como verificar se é um fim de semana?

Tentei usar o `Calendar`, mas parece que só funciona com `Date`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

É só usar o [método `getDayOfWeek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfWeek()). Isso retorna um elemento do [`enum DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html):

```
public static boolean fimDeSemana(LocalDate ld) {
    DayOfWeek d = ld.getDayOfWeek();
    return d == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || d == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
}
```

Aqui vai um teste completo dele:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;

class Teste {

    public static boolean fimDeSemana(LocalDate ld) {
        DayOfWeek d = ld.getDayOfWeek();
        return d == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || d == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 19))); // false, terça-feira
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 20))); // false, quarta-feira
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 21))); // false, quinta-feira
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 22))); // false, sexta-feira
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 23))); // true, sábado
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 24))); // true, domingo
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 25))); // false, segunda-feira
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 26))); // false, terça-feira
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 27))); // false, quarta-feira
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 28))); // false, quinta-feira
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 29))); // false, sexta-feira
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 30))); // true, sábado
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 31))); // true, domingo
        System.out.println(fimDeSemana(LocalDate.of(2018,  1,  1))); // false, segunda-feira
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/CACkNI)

Answer (score 2):

A [resposta do Victor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/264701/112052) está correta, só queria acrescentar uma outra alternativa.

Ao invés de um método estático, você também pode criar uma [`java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalQuery.html):

```
// TemporalQuery que verifica se é fim de semana
TemporalQuery<Boolean> fds = t -> {
    DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from(t);
    return dow == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || dow == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
};
```

Para usá-la, basta usar o método [`query`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#query-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery-):

```
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 21);
boolean fimDeSemana = dt.query(fds); // false
```

A grande vantagem é que uma `TemporalQuery` pode ser usada com qualquer tipo que implemente [`java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html), como por exemplo [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) e [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) (e qualquer outra classe que implemente `TemporalAccessor` e possua um dia da semana):

```
boolean fimDeSemana = ZonedDateTime.now().query(fds);
```

Você também pode usá-la diretamente com um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), por exemplo, caso sua entrada seja uma `String`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
boolean fimDeSemana = fmt.parse("21/12/2017", fds);
```

Apesar do método estático funcionar perfeitamente, eu acho que usar uma `TemporalQuery` é mais flexível, pelos motivos acima. Mas claro que tudo depende dos seus casos de uso.

---

Claro que se a classe em questão não tiver dia da semana, uma exception será lançada:

```
// lança exception porque LocalTime não tem dia da semana
LocalTime.now().query(fds);
```

Answer (score -1):

public class HoraDiasDataLocalService {

```
public static LocalTime horaLocal() {

    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("kk:mm:ss");
    CharSequence localTime = LocalTime.now().toString();


    return LocalTime.parse(localTime, dateTimeFormatter);

}

public static LocalDate dataLocal() {

        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
        CharSequence localDate = LocalDate.now().toString();


        return LocalDate.parse(localDate, dateTimeFormatter);

    }
```

// MAXIMO DE 3 DIAS UTEIS PARA RESERVA O LIVRO.............

```
public static LocalDate dataReservaLimite() {

    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");

    LocalDate localDatePlus3 = LocalDate.now().plusDays(3); 

    LocalDate localDateAnalyzed = verificarFinalDeSemana(localDatePlus3);


    return LocalDate.parse(localDateAnalyzed.toString(), dateTimeFormatter);

}
```

// MAXIMO DE 10 DIAS UTEIS PARA ALUGAR  O LIVRO.............

```
public static LocalDate dataEmprestimoDevolucao() {

    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");

    LocalDate localDatePlus10 = LocalDate.now().plusDays(10);   

    LocalDate localDateAnalyzed = verificarFinalDeSemana(localDatePlus10);


    return LocalDate.parse(localDateAnalyzed.toString(), dateTimeFormatter);


}



public static LocalDate dataRenovacaoEmprestimo(Long idEmprestimo) {


    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");

    LocalDate localDatePlus10 = LocalDate.now().plusDays(10);   

    LocalDate localDateAnalyzed = verificarFinalDeSemana(localDatePlus10);


    return LocalDate.parse(localDateAnalyzed.toString(), dateTimeFormatter);


}


//"PROXIMO DIA UTIL"
private static LocalDate verificarFinalDeSemana(LocalDate dataAgendada) {

    LocalDate dataAnalyzed = dataAgendada;

    if (dataAgendada.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY){

        dataAnalyzed = dataAgendada.plusDays(2);

    } else if(dataAgendada.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {

        dataAnalyzed = dataAgendada.plusDays(1);

    } 
    return dataAnalyzed;


}
```

Answer (score -4):

Eu consegui da seguinte forma...

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Data{
         public static void main(String[] args) {

         //Instanciando a classe Calendar juntamente com a classe GregorianCalendar
         Calendar data = new GregorianCalendar();

         //Condicação do que diz qual o dia da semana apartir da data do sistema
         switch(data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Domingo");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Segunda-feira");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Terça-feira");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Quarta-feira");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Quinta-feira");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Sexta-feira");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("Sabado");
                break;
        }

        //COMPLETANDO... CASO SEJA FIM DE SEMANA OU MEIO DE SEMANA...
        if ((data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 7) || (data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 1){
            System.out.println("Fim de Semana");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dias úteis");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\nFIM DO PROGRAMA!!!");
    } 
}
```

OBS: Eu me ative a classe Calendar, então eu realmente não respondia a pergunta feita, mas fiz esse outro algoritmo e parece que deu certo tmb...

```
import java.time.*;
public class Data{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LocalDate data = LocalDate.now();
    DayOfWeek sabado = DayOfWeek.of(6);
    DayOfWeek domingo = DayOfWeek.of(7);

    if (data.getDayOfWeek().equals(sabado)){
        System.out.println("Fim de Semana!");
    } else if(data.getDayOfWeek().equals(domingo)) {
        System.out.println("Fim de Semana!");
    } else{
        System.out.println("Qualquer dia comum da semana!");
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nFIM DO PROGRAMA!!!");
}
```

}

Comment: `Como verificar se um LocalDate é um fim-de-semana?` - a duvida é com LocalDate, além do seu código não dizer quando é fim de semana, não está usando o tipo questionado.

Comment: Desculpas eu pensei só em especificar os dias, mas creio q agora a pergunta foi respondida, eu espero.

Comment: Por favor, releia a pergunta.

Comment: Poxa chapa, eu realmente viajei!!! Dessa vez eu consegui?