# Comparar datas usando LocalDate

Tags: java, data

Preciso fazer uma comparação de datas da seguinte forma:

```
dat_envio_shopping + 2 dias úteis < [data hoje]
```

Até então tenho feito assim:

```
boletoSerasa.getEnvio().isBefore(LocalDate.now())
```

Minha dúvida fica nesses "+2 dias úteis".

Como posso fazer essa comparação de "dat_envio_shopping + 2 dias úteis"?

Comment: Defina dias úteis.

Comment: Segunda à sexta-feira.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para somar dias ao `LocalDate`, use o [método `plus(int, TemporalUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#plus(long,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

Para verificar se é um dia útil, recomendo [essa outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/264701/132).

Dessa forma, para somar dois dias úteis, você pode fazer isso:

```
public static boolean fimDeSemana(LocalDate ld) {
    DayOfWeek d = ld.getDayOfWeek();
    return d == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || d == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
}

public static LocalDate mais2DiasUteis(LocalDate ld) {
    LocalDate novaData = ld.plus(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    while (fimDeSemana(novaData)) {
        novaData = novaData.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    }
    return novaData;
}
```

Para comparar se uma data é anterior a outra:

```
boolean antes = algumaData.isBefore(hoje);
```

Eis um teste completo:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

class TesteData {
    public static boolean fimDeSemana(LocalDate ld) {
        DayOfWeek d = ld.getDayOfWeek();
        return d == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || d == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
    }

    public static LocalDate mais2DiasUteis(LocalDate ld) {
        LocalDate novaData = ld.plus(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        while (fimDeSemana(novaData)) {
            novaData = novaData.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        }
        return novaData;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

        LocalDate algumaData1 = mais2DiasUteis(LocalDate.parse("04/09/2018", fmt));
        LocalDate hoje1 = LocalDate.parse("05/09/2018", fmt); //LocalDate.now();
        boolean antes1 = algumaData1.isBefore(hoje1);
        System.out.println(antes1 + " - " + fmt.format(algumaData1) + " - " + fmt.format(hoje1));

        LocalDate algumaData2 = mais2DiasUteis(LocalDate.parse("06/09/2018", fmt));
        LocalDate hoje2 = LocalDate.parse("10/09/2018", fmt); //LocalDate.now();
        boolean antes2 = algumaData2.isBefore(hoje2);
        System.out.println(antes2 + " - " + fmt.format(algumaData2) + " - " + fmt.format(hoje2));

        LocalDate algumaData3 = mais2DiasUteis(LocalDate.parse("06/09/2018", fmt));
        LocalDate hoje3 = LocalDate.parse("11/09/2018", fmt); //LocalDate.now();
        boolean antes3 = algumaData3.isBefore(hoje3);
        System.out.println(antes3 + " - " + fmt.format(algumaData3) + " - " + fmt.format(hoje3));
    }
}
```

A saída é essa:

```
false - 06/09/2018 - 05/09/2018
false - 10/09/2018 - 10/09/2018
true - 10/09/2018 - 11/09/2018
```

Observe que a data do dia 04/09 (terça-feira) foi jogada para 06/09 (quinta-feira). Já a data de 06/09 (quinta-feira) foi jogada para 10/09 (segunda-feira), pulando o fim-de-semana.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/NMtZzo)

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é somar 2 dias, e caso o resultado caia em um sábado ou domingo, ajustar a data para a próxima segunda-feira.

Você pode usar a classe `java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters`, que já possui um *adjuster* pronto para retornar a próxima segunda:

```
LocalDate dataEnvio = ...
// somar dois dias
LocalDate doisDiasDepois = dataEnvio.plusDays(2);
// se caiu em um fim de semana (sábado ou domingo)
if (doisDiasDepois.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY
    || doisDiasDepois.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
    // ajustar para a próxima segunda-feira
    doisDiasDepois = doisDiasDepois.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
}

if (doisDiasDepois.isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
    ...
}
```

Se quiser, pode usar `import static` para deixar o código um pouco mais legível:

```
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.next;
import static java.time.DayOfWeek.*;

// ....
// se caiu em um fim de semana
if (doisDiasDepois.getDayOfWeek() == SATURDAY
    || doisDiasDepois.getDayOfWeek() == SUNDAY) {
    // ajustar para a próxima segunda-feira
    doisDiasDepois = doisDiasDepois.with(next(MONDAY));
}
```

---

Outra alternativa é implementar seu próprio `TemporalAdjuster`. A diferença é que este trabalha com a interface `java.time.temporal.Temporal` (ao invés de trabalhar com um tipo específico, como `LocalDate`).

A lógica é a mesma (somar 2 dias, se cair em fim de semana, ajusta para a próxima segunda), mas como `Temporal` não possui os métodos `plusDays` e `getDayOfWeek`, a implementação fica um pouco diferente:

```
public TemporalAdjuster somarDiasUteis(long dias) {
    return temporal -> {
        // somar a quantidade de dias
        temporal = temporal.plus(dias, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from(temporal);
        // se cai em fim de semana, ajusta para a próxima segunda
        if (dow == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || dow == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
            temporal = temporal.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
        }
        return temporal;
    };
}
```

Para usar, basta passar o resultado para o método `with`:

```
LocalDate dataEnvio = ...
LocalDate doisDiasDepois = dataEnvio.with(somarDiasUteis(2));
```

A vantagem é que este *adjuster* serve para qualquer tipo que implemente `Temporal` (ou seja, todos os tipos nativos da API, como `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, etc), desde que eles tenham os campos de data, claro (`LocalTime`, por exemplo, não tem dia, então não funcionaria com esta classe).